# Repeat multiple searches in vim

Tags: vim

I've an HTML file with many URLs, and I want to locate a specific URL strings in succession. For that I use the search pattern `/sometext/;?http?` so that cursor gets placed at the beginning of the URL string.

I want to repeat the search (both of them) for the next URL using `n` or `N` command, but the search is repeated for only the second pattern. Is there a way to repeat both search patterns at once (other than `q/k<CR>`)?

Comment: Note that there’s now a [vi.se].

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to record your search:

```
qq
/sometext/;?http<CR>
q
```

and play it back with `@q` instead of `n`:

```
@q
@q
@q
```

Comment: You can also do `3@q`

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for `\ze` to mark the end of a pattern's match.

```
/http\ze\_.*sometext/
```

For more help see: `:h /\zs`